# Rails Sorting by Algorithm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to sort my links using an algorithm, all the information needed can be derived from values in my `Links` table. How can I return items sorted by the item's calculated `Score`?

Schema https://gist.github.com/1326044

Index Action https://gist.github.com/1326045

Time Calculation https://gist.github.com/1326050

Algorithm

```
  # Score = (P-1) / (T+2)^G 
  # P = points of an item (and -1 is to negate submitters vote)
  # T = time since submission (in hours)
  # G = Gravity, defaults to 1.8
```

Comment: I'm still a newbie, I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by at database level. I want to avoid using custom SQL because my production code is hosted on heroku which uses postgresql, does that answer it?

Comment: I've been reading Rails 3 Active Record and Adv Active Record chapters hoping that I could come up with a linear equation to calculate each record's score on the fly and sort. It's probably not very efficient, but I could clean it up later.

Comment: I mean, do you want to do this with a database query (doesn't seem possible given the time constraints) or at the Rails level? The simplest solution for me seems to be taking a couple of records based on time, calculate their scores in memory and then show it to the user.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares: I do think sorting within Rails is the only option, that's what I suggest in my answer

Comment: How would I implement the simplest solution?

Comment: @Dru: the answer I provide is pretty simple and clean no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do as follows:

First, in your model:

```
after_initialize :calculate_score

attr_accessor :score

def calculate_score
  unless self.new_record?
    time_elapsed = (Time.zone.now - self.created_at) / 3600
    self.score = (self.points-1) / (time_elapsed+2)^G # I don't know how you retrieve G
  end
end
```

In your controller:

```
@links = Link.all.sort_by(&:score)
```

Comment: I've been looking for documentation to understand after_initialize, will this recalculate scores before they are pulled from the table?

Comment: this will calculate the score each time you get an object from the database, so it will be refreshed too

Comment: @Dru - The [Active Record Callbacks documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) might help a little. In a nutshell, whenever you successfully find an record with `find`, or create a new object, the `after_initialize` callback will be triggered for that object.